# In mysql master-slave Replication which server requests the other?

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to setup mysql replication between two servers one of them is my localhost and the other is online server.
I have all availability to make any one of them the master.
But according to that my localhost server doesn't have a static IP, i need to know which server of the two (master & slave) is the one which requests the other for doing updates.
Does the master sends the binlog updates, or the slave is the one which requests for new updates periodically ? so i will make it the localhost.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

according to this reference: [Get MySQL Replication up and running in 5 minutes](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/get-mysql-replication-up-and-running-in-5-minutes), Slave must access master to initialize.

```sql
slave> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='192.168.0.31',
 -> MASTER_USER='repl_user',
 -> MASTER_PASSWORD='billy',
 -> MASTER_LOG_FILE='',
 -> MASTER_LOG_POS=4;
```

So, you can setup slave in localhost and master in remote host with accessible IP and port.

This is a client server communication:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Logically*, the Primary 'pushes' data to the Replica.

*Actually*, the Replica connects to the Primary and 'pulls' the data.

So, it is more important to have a static IP, or a DNS lookup, so that the Replica can find the Primary.

Comment: Are there workarounds for that? I have a scenario where the slave is in a network segment that can not establish connections to the master, but the other direction is accepted.

Comment: @Benni - `ssh` with suitable options can establish the connection in the "other" direction.  (Sorry, I don't have the details.)

Comment: Sure, but then we are in "circumventing the decision from the networking team by creating your own tunnel" territory :)